# Dúvidas sobre type Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Queria saber se dava para usar o `type` assim:

```
media = input("Digite o numero: ")
média = input("Digite outro numero: ")

if media == type('str'):
    print("oi")

else:
    print("Tchau")
```

Ou seja, para verificar se a variável `media` é `str`, e se for, imprimir uma mensagem.

Se não for, daí ele continua.

Queria usar isso para uma calculadora. Caso ele coloque algo que não seja `int` ou `float`, dizer que não pode colocar caracteres em tal lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim, só colocar o *type* do outro lado.

```
media = 'exemplo'

if type(media) == str:
    print('oi')
else:
    print('tchau')
```

Comment: está certo - mas o mais comum é usar a chamada  `isinstance`. Ficaria: `if isinstance(media, str):`